# CollectionView content goes under NavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uicollectionview

I added a `UICollectionViewController` using IB. Then I added a `UINavigationBar` in code:

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init]; 
[navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
[navBar setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:navBar];
```

All works fine except the fact that the collection view content is hidden by the navigation bar. It doesn't only scroll beneath the navigation bar but in fact displays beneath it when first loaded.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a standalone navigation bar? It's probably a bad idea. Embed your view controller in a UINavigationController, and make sure the top contraint of your UICollectionView is set to the top layout guide and not the view.

Comment: Because there is no actual navigation going on. It is a standalone view. I just need a top & bottom bars.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your content offset of the collection view. I'd try either 44 (height of nav bar) or 64 (height of nav bar + status bar)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is adding `UINavigationBar` on `self.view` which is `UICollectionView`.
You may use simple `UIViewController` with `UICollectionView` as subview of its view. Then after adding `UINavigationBar` you have to change `collectionView.frame`.